# Hadoop: Mapper logs are not printing in application logs

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

I have log statements in my mapper using slf4j/log4j that are not showing up in application(port 8090) logs.

Do I have to configure anything for this in hadoop 2.x? Everything works well in 1.x

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Logging works bit differently in Hadoop 2.x

**Please follow steps mentioned below:**

1.You will find container-log4j.properties in hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager jar file, extract it (make your Custom changes) and run below command

```
jar uf /home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.2.0.jar container-log4j.properties
```

2.Alternatively yo can make changes in file hadoop-config.sh(you can specify custom changes for logger in line below)

```
  HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Dhadoop.root.logger=${HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER:-INFO,console}"
```